# spliting java string based on bunch of non alpha characters

Tags: java

I have a string some thing like `my+*%name===is+jhon!#and&*^I$stay===in^&$#@US`. I want output as

```
s[0]="my"

s[1]="+*%"

s[2]="name"

s[3]="==="

s[4]="is"

s[5]="+"

s[6]="jhon"

s[7]="!#"

s[8]="and"

s[9]="&*^"

s[10]="I"

s[11]="$"

s[12]="stay"

s[13]="==="
```

etc.

Please note that it is not following any pattern and the bunch of nonalphanumeric chars vary as the string will be dynamic data string

Comment: And what is your question? What have you written and what problem did you have? Have you tried debugging your code to see why it doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: Dear Peter
  
I tried using split but Iam not able to catch the non alpha chars to a string . I want to catch both the bunch of Alphanumeric as well as nonAlphanumberic to an array of String.

String s1="my+%name===is+jhon!#and&^I$stay===in^&$#@US";
 
  String[] nowSplit = s1.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

   
   for (int i = 0; i < nowSplit .length; i++)
     
       {
   System.out.println("nowSplit "+i+"                               :" + nowSplit [i]);
   }

Comment: Since you already have a regex, you can search for index of next occurrence of the pattern in a loop and keep adding them to an array.

Comment: Dear Amar

The biggest problem is - it is not following any pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to split bunch of alpha characters

```
 void separateMyString(){
    String str = "my+%name===is+jhon!#and&^I$stay===in^&$#@US";
 ArrayList<String> stringdata = new ArrayList<String>();
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 boolean isInSameString = true;
 boolean prevStringValue = Character.isLetter(str.charAt(0));
 for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
     isInSameString = (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))== prevStringValue) ?true:false;
    if(i == (str.length() -1)){
        isInSameString = false;
    }
     prevStringValue = Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i));

         if(!isInSameString){
             if(i == (str.length() -1)){
                 sb.append(str.charAt(i));
                }
             stringdata.add(sb.toString());
         sb = new StringBuffer();
         }

         sb.append(str.charAt(i));

 }
 System.out.println("~~~"+stringdata);
}
```

OutPUT= `~~~[my, +%, name, ===, is, +, jhon, !#, and, &^, I, $, stay, ===, in, ^&$#@, US]`

Comment: Dear Sunil
  Thanks for your valuable input but one small issue in the above code. If you observe, the last value "US" is not getting in the output. Last part is not getting added to the list

Comment: Check my answer now. it gives you same output as you want

Comment: Thanks a lot sunil. It helped me as desired